Visual Studio Code Mermaid Error: Maximum text size in diagram exceeded
Getting an error message: Maximum text size in diagram exceeded.
I apologize up front for my ignorance of this subject but could really use some help. I have found several posts that specify to make this config change but none of them specify in detail where to do this.
I have tried the following to no avail:

I put %%{init: { 'maxTextSize': 999999999 } }%% at the start of my diagram.mmd file and still get the error.
%%{init: { 'maxTextSize': 9999999999999 } }%%
erDiagram


I got a defaultConfig.js file from mermaid github, renamed to mermaidConfig.js and changed the maxTextSize in it. Put the name of the file in settings.json, there was a setting there with quotes and no file name. I added the filename but still get the error.


     { "mermaid-editor.preview.defaultMermaidConfig": "mermaidConfig.js" }


